# rsync port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: rsync

I want to make a backup for my remote server folders(ubunto server)to another remote sever (Linux server). but once I run this command from the the first server it dispalys me an error message:

```
 rsync -raz --progress  firstdirectoy root@serverIP:/home
```

The displayed messahe is:

```
ssh: connect to host <serverIP> port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

But the same command from the server 2 to the server 1 works fine and the folder is nicely copyed into the server1.

How can I escape the connexion error in order to copy my folder from server 1 to server 2 throw rsync?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like server2 has no active ssh daemon while server1 has.
Try to run ssh daemon or use raw rsync protocol and rsync daemon.

Comment: but it do involve ssh daemon

Comment: `ssh: connect to host <serverIP> port 22: Connection timed out`
Indicates that ssh daemon on target machine either not run or not accessible. Can you log in via ssh or something like that?

Comment: I connect to my second server ssh username@IP and it works . what is missing?

Comment: Probably the second server has working and accessible ssh.
If you are using Linux try `ps -ef | grep ssh` on both machines and show the output.

Comment: mack      3050  3016  0 Jan20 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/seahorse-agent --execute x-session-manager
root      4830     1  0  2013 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     22038  4830  0 13:17 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/1

Answer (score 1):

If it's a connection timeout because your SSH server is slow to respond, you can tweak the timeout in rsync:

`rsync -e 'ssh -o ConnectTimeout=120'`

Else it may be a missing SSH daemon (sshd) on server 2 as stated by @geov, or a closed port on your firewall. You may start by testing an SSH login:

`ssh user@serverIP`

And see if it's working or not. Probably `nmap serverIP` will help you too, stating if SSH is running or not.

And please do **NOT** use `root` user for your rsync copy!

Answer (score 0):

if you wait for a long time, the prompt appears

I think that your server2's IP is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error appeared when attempting to rsync between two AWS EC2 instances where the two instances were not a part of the same security group.

1. [Overview of how to create security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)
2. [How to change the security groups of the instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/37088/how-to-add-a-security-group-to-a-running-ec2-instance)
3. [Allow instances within the same security group to communicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/938301/ssh-between-ec2-instances-not-permitted)